# Paul Morphy vs Henry Bird missing games.

Tags: history, morphy

The Historical Chess Ratings [page](http://www.edochess.ca/players/p23.html) claims that Paul Morphy played 12 games with Henry Bird, with a final score of `10.5 - 1.5` (Kasparov's book My Great Predecessors Part I also mentions this (page 55), claiming Morphy won 10, lost 1 and drew 1). However, I was able to find only [5](http://www.chessgames.com/perl/chess.pl?pid=16002&pid2=10411) of these games online. Do we have a record anywhere of the moves of the other 7 games?

Comment: Those five might be the only games between Morphy and Bird that have survived, see for instance http://timkr.home.xs4all.nl/ChessTutor/morphy.htm

Comment: @DagOskarMadsen post this as an answer? Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The five games mentioned might be the only games between Morphy and Bird that are preserved. Collections that claim to include all known Morphy games, only contain those five between the two, see for instance [The full Morphy](http://timkr.home.xs4all.nl/ChessTutor/morphy.htm). Also, written accounts seem to suggest that the games they played were not part of an official match, they just played some games while Morphy was waiting for a reply from Staunton [(Link)](http://www.edochess.ca/batgirl/morphybio7.html).